# Submitting a large array from a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have an issue, I have data being sent to the user who needs to check the datais correct before submitting it to the model. Usually I would send datya from a controller but I'm not sure how to do it in this circumstance..

This is what I have

CONTROLLER

```
 $questions = $this->assessment_model->get_list_questions($data['list']);
 $this->load->view('quiz', $questions);
```

My view than outputs $questions to the user. (Questions is a BIG array)

VIEW

```
foreach ($questions['data'] as $q) {
    echo $q;
};
echo "<a href'WHAT_GOES_HERE'>Save Question list</a>"
```

Once the user has clicked on the link I need to submit the data in $questions to another controller... Is there a strait forward way to do this?

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller needs a correction:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$list['questions'] = $this->assessment_model->get_list_questions($data['list']);
$this->load->view('quiz', $list);
```

In the view:

```
<?php
    $this->session->set_flashdata('Questions', $questions);
    $this->load->helper('url');
    anchor('controller2', 'Click here');
?>
```

On the second controller:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$questions = $this->session->flashdata('Questions');
```

For help: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Hi That throws up an error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$session

Filename: views/assessment_generated.php

Line Number: 28

Any ideas?

Comment: I have modified the answer. Plz check

Comment: Yes, though I decided to echo an "a" tag instead of using the anchor. It gave me a little more flexability